# Attribute p:prefix not allowed here

Tags: xml, spring, spring-mvc

I've created a project with spring mvc and in my `dispatcherServlet.xml` file

```
<bean id="jspViewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/views/"
          p:suffix=".jsp"
            />
```

`p:prefix` and `p:suffix` are not allowed. How can I solve this issue? I've used SpringVersion `3.2.3.RELEASE`

Comment: How do u solve your problem ?

Answer (score 4):

You need to add the p-namespace declaration: `xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"`

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
```

See Spring reference: [Chapter 5.4.2.6 XML shortcut with the p-namespace](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-p-namespace)

Comment: **xmlns:p=http://www.springframework.org/schema/p** It was already added and I found out this link [http://www.springframework.org/schema/p] also cannot resolved. Why is that ?

Comment: I came across the same issue. xmlns:p=springframework.org/schema/p already added.

Answer (score -2):

> 

```html
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd 
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.1.xsd           
            ">
```

Comment: you should explain how your answer solves the problem i.e you need to add the spring framework namespaces to the top of your xml beans definition file. In particular the part you need is `xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"`. Note that nothing requires you to use p:. These are simply being used by convention. You could rewrite your XML to use a: everywhere - as long as they are defined to map to the same XML namespaces. (This is why they need to be defined.)